# Connecting to VPN disconnects other connections

Tags: openvpn

When I connect to my company's VPN, my IM gets disconnected. Same is true if I'm streaming video. Have I configured it wrong? I am using OpenVPN on Ubuntu 12.10. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably down to the server configuration of your company. Do you have control of that? It sounds like it is pushing down a default route to ensure *all* traffic (including your IM and video streaming traffic) traverses the company network. If you don't want this behaviour then you probably want "split-tunneling". I'm not an OpenVPN user but a quick search threw up this thread which might help:

[OpenVPN split tunneling](https://forums.openvpn.net/topic11501.html)

Comment: Other people on Macs at my company don't have the same problem. I'm guessing it's a config on my VPN client but I'm not sure which one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but here goes:

I suppose that your OpenVPN server pushes its gateway as default gateway to your clients. OpenVPN now allows clients to ignore it via the ignore-redirect-gateway directive that can be added to OpenVPN client configurations:

https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway

The exact directive to add to your client file would be:

```
pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway
```